# Camera usage notification at mozilla firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, geckodriver

I'm writting an automatied test with using selenium dirver and geckoDriver for mozilla firefox v56. The application which I'm testing always ask user to allow the camera usage and always this notification is displayed:

[image]

The problem is that, the Mozilla browser session which is created by geckoDriver does not saved settings where I always allow this page to use the camera driver.
I'm talking about this solution: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-page-info-window

I cannot find any parameter in ***about::config*** page which which I can run firefox to never ask about this permission again. Can I ask for your help?

Comment: One solution is that the first ting your code does it so remove that popup. I have done this on many sites where there is always a popup when you open the website.

Comment: it's not a pont. Firefox have to get this permissions to use camera, because only when it will get it, the page displays web elements.